# Module not found: Can't resolve './App.css' in '/Users/ThomasHunt/Desktop/portfolio/src'

Tags: reactjs

I have removed the app.css file from my folders and I get this error. I know its such a rookie mistake but I can't seem to find a fix.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Find the file still importing it and remove the import, or restore `./App.css`. The error should tell you exactly what file and line the error is occurring.

Comment: Double-check within the `App.js` or any other `*.js` file, and remove the line that import the `App.css`.